# Make Such Array For TreeView in PHP Where parent chid hierarchy directly did not exists

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, treeview

I have a function which gives me TreeList if I give him $treeData = array(id=1,Name=Abc, ParentId=null). Normally I have table structure like this so there is no problem to provide such array. Problem starts when I have no such structure in table but my client want TreeList for such structure where parent child hierarchy is not directly exists.
What Table Structure I have

1. Types
2. Subjects
3. Topics
4. Lessons
5. LessonTypes

In LessonTypes I have TypeId, SubjectId, TopicId, LessonId

I tried to make an array for my function but it is not quite good please see my code:

```
 private function makeTreeDataArray(){
    $treeDataArr = array();
    $resourceTestTypesArr = array();
    $topicArr = array();
    $lessonArr = array();
    $testTypeIdPrefix = 'TestType@';
    $subjectIdPrefix = 'Subject@';
    $topicIdPrefix = 'Topic@';
    // $model = new ResourceTestType();

    //Get All TestTypes into treeDataArr
    $model = new Option();
    $TestTypes = $model->where('Type','TestType')->get();
    foreach ($TestTypes as $k => $TT) {
        $testTypeId = $testTypeIdPrefix . $TT->Id;
        $treeDataArr[] = array('Id' => $testTypeId, 'Name'=>$TT->Option, 'ParentId' => null);

        $resourceTestTypesArr[] = $TT->resourceTestTypes()->get();
    }

    // return ($resourceTestTypes);
    //****Get All Subjects Of TestType
    foreach ($resourceTestTypesArr as $i =>$RTTs) {

        foreach ($RTTs as $j => $RTT) {
            $subjectId = $subjectIdPrefix . $RTT->SubjectId;
            $resourceId =$RTT->ResourceId;
            $subjectName = $RTT->subject()->first()->Name;
            $testTypeIdAsParentId = $testTypeIdPrefix.$RTT->TestTypeId;

            $treeDataArr[] = array('Id' => $subjectId, 'Name'=>$subjectName, 'ParentId' => $testTypeIdAsParentId);


            //*** Create dataset for Topics
            $topicId = $topicIdPrefix.$RTT->TopicId;
            $topicIdWithoutPrefix = $RTT->TopicId;
            $topicName = Option::getOptionById('Topics',$topicIdWithoutPrefix)->Display;
            $topicArr[] = array('topicId' => $topicId, 'topicName'=>$topicName, 'SubjectId' => $subjectId, 'LessonId' => $resourceId);
        }
    }

    // return ($topicArr);
    //Get All Topics Of Subject
    foreach ($topicArr as $i =>$T) {
        $topicId = $T['topicId'];
        $lessonId = $T['LessonId'];
        $treeDataArr[] = array('Id' => $topicId, 'Name'=> $T['topicName'], 'ParentId' => $T['SubjectId']);

        $lessonName = Lesson::find($lessonId)->Name;
        $lessonArr[] = array('lessonId' => $lessonId, 'lessonName'=>$lessonName, 'topicId' => $topicId);
    }

    // return ($lessonArr);
    //Get All Lessons Of Topics
    foreach ($lessonArr as $i =>$L) {
        $treeDataArr[] = array('Id' => $L['lessonId'], 'Name'=> $L['lessonName'], 'ParentId' => 'Topic@'.$L['topicId']);
    }
    $result = array_unique($treeDataArr,SORT_REGULAR);
    // $result = array_unique($treeDataArr);
    return $result;
}
```

And Result of the function is:

1. -> A-Type

   - -> A-Subject Of A-Type
   - - -> A-Topic Of A-Subject
   - - - -> A-Lesson Of A-Topic
   - - -> B-Topic Of A-Subject
   - - - -> A-Lesson Of B-Topic
2. -> B-Type
3. -> A-Subject Of A-Type

Notice: A-Subject Appear again here which is not correct it should be appear only inside the A-Type
It happens all others also. Please help me what's wrong with my code. Thanks in advance